# I can’t drop items in super smash bros brawl

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

I was playing Super Smash Bros Brawl (after the release of Super Smash Bros Ultimate) and I played a my main man Yoshi and I picked up an item. I saw another item better than the one I had. However couldn’t drop my current item so I couldn’t pick up the new one.

How do I drop items in Super Smash Bros Brawl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to drop items:

1) Dropping - This lets you just drop the item where you are and is much faster than throwing it. Just grab while not pressing any direction and your character will drop the item where you are.

2) Throwing - Press a direction on the left stick like you are running and press grab; your character will throw the item in that direction.

3) Getting hit - If you get hit enough, you will eventually drop whatever item you are holding. I believe it is dependent on your damage/the attack's damage/knockback but there is some randomness involved.

Comment: Might be worth noting that all 3 of these will work whether your character is grounded or in the air. And in addition, items cannot be dropped while using [Peach's float](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Floating).

Answer (score 0):

Literally just press the grab button. If you want to throw it (which can be used to fight enemies) then move the left stick (or hold a direction on the D-Pad) in the direction you want to throw it in as you press the attack button.